# Cypress 10 - How can I run test files in order

Tags: cypress

Previously it should be set up in cypress.json.
Like

```
  testFiles: [
  "e2e/register.cy.ts",
  "e2e/buyGiftCertificate.cy.ts",
  "e2e/buyMembershipCertificate.cy.ts"
]
```

But after migrating to Cypress 10 the place for it is cypress.config.ts
There should be a pattern but how to order tests it's not clear

Comment: What is the reason for wanting specs to run in specific order?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `npx cypress run`, you can do exactly the same thing, except use `specPattern` instead of `testFiles`.

The following will run the test (only these tests) in the order `spec2.cy.js`, `spec3.cy.js`, `spec1.cy.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: [
      "cypress/e2e/spec2.cy.js",
      "cypress/e2e/spec3.cy.js",
      "cypress/e2e/spec1.cy.js",
    ]
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file inside your e2e folder as `tests-in-order.cy.ts` and inside that file import the tests in order you want them to execute:

```js
//Run tests in the intended order

import './register.cy.ts'
import './buyGiftCertificate.cy.ts'
import './buyMembershipCertificate.cy.ts'
```

And then execute the file using the command (from cli):

```js
npx cypress run --spec=cypress/e2e/tests-in-order.cy.ts
```

For Test Runner, just click on the file to execute.

Comment: Is it normal that test breaks when they are not in specific order.. I am getting the same issue but i am thinking that why must my test be dependent on an order...